# Invoke Geiser with plt-r5rs rather than Racket?

Tags: emacs, scheme, lisp, racket, geiser

When using Geiser and Emacs for Scheme programming, how do I set Geiser to invoke plt-r5rs legacy scheme, or possibly the R6RS variant, instead of Racket in "racket" mode?

I want Racket, to function in R5RS (or possibly R6RS) mode within the REPL rather than in racket mode, which is deviating more and more from "standard" scheme.

Comment: FYI, I edited my answer below to have more info and to work better than before and you might find it acceptable now.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `geiser-racket-init-file`:

```
(require r5rs/init)
```

Then stick this advice somewhere in your Emacs initialization file(s):

```
(defadvice run-racket (after enter-r5rs activate)
  (switch-to-geiser-module "r5rs"))
```

That should give you an R5RS-ish experience in Geiser.

EDIT:

I had to deal with this issue recently and found that my above answer was insufficient. For starters, simply switching the module to `r5rs` did not, for some strange reason, load symbols that should have been in that module, e.g., `set-car!` or `set-cdr!`. I found that using `geiser-repl-import-module` instead of `switch-to-geiser-module` works better because it will actually load expected symbols such as `set-car!`, `set-cdr!`, etc. Additionally, the behavior of using `(geiser-repl-import-module "r5rs")` matches the behavior that one gets by running `#lang r5rs` in DrRacket, so it's probably sufficient for most people. However, if you still want to run the `plt-r5rs` executable in Geiser, you could try the following:

```
(progn
  (flet ((geiser-racket--parameters () nil))
    (let ((geiser-racket-binary "plt-r5rs")
          (geiser-repl-skip-version-check-p t))
      (ignore-errors
        (run-geiser 'racket))
      ;; to keep your racket history from getting clobbered
      (setq-local geiser-repl-history-filename "~/.emacs.d/.plt-r5rs_history"))))
```

Unfortunately, the resultant REPL functionality from that snippet of code is rather primitive (e.g., you cannot auto-complete symbols). This is because we're removing the `geiser-racket--parameters` since those parameters are incompatible with `plt-r5rs` and R5RS itself. You'd get quite similar functionality and less convolution by doing `C-u M-x run-scheme RET plt-r5rs`.